# INTEL-XDK and Source/Version control - Is it even supported?

Tags: git, cordova, version-control, intel-xdk, plasticscm

I am very new to phonegap development and just had a INTEL-XDK setup. I am wondering how can I have it work integrated with my source control system. For Source Control, I have Plastic SCM and GitHub.

I come from the Visual Studio and VSS/Team Foundation Server/Plastic SCM background, so can't think of having to start coding without having a version control system in place.

I explored all over INTEL-XDK IDE, searched across the internet, and I find it surprising that there is no mention of source control for this IDE!

Answer (score 4):

The Intel XDK does not prescribe a source code control system, you can use whichever you prefer or whichever works best for your project.

That said, the Brackets editor that is built into the XDK (on the Develop tab) does include a git extension that is very convenient for use with github accounts, local git repos and private git remote repos. Once you get your git repo(s) setup in your project it works very nicely (I use it all the time for syncing with my git repos, it's easier than using the command-line). When you have the editor open, check the "File --> Extension Manager..." menu item and you'll find the brackets-git extension (docs here https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git).

I've always setup my git repos by hand when using this extension, so I don't know how well it works at initializing a repo. In any event, once you've got your project setup as a git repo, it works quite nicely.

One thing to be aware of, there are a few files that are hidden from the Brackets file manager view but are part of your project directory (in particular, *.xdk* files, might be a few others). The git extension will pick those up, but it won't display them in its list of files to commit. I've found that if you want to include them in your git repo (you might want to include the *.xdk file, but not the *.xdke file) you just need to check the "select all" button using the git extension file list checker and then uncheck the files you don't want to use. When you push the commit button you'll see those hidden files in the list of files to be included in the commit. That point can be a little confusing, but will make more sense once you play around with the extension.

Also, the git command-line utilities are NOT installed as part of the extension, they assume that git is already installed on your system and available in the path. See the git extension docs for info on how to install git on your system if you don't already have it there.

Comment: p.s. I highly recommend that you install the various hint/lint extensions, they are very helpful with regard to finding obscure bugs in your code. :)

Answer (score -1):

There is not a specific Plastic SCM plugin for INTEL-XDK, but it doesn´t mean that you can´t use Plastic as SCM.

Plastic has a transparent SCM feature: http://www.plasticscm.com/features/transparent-scm.aspx

It means that you can directly modify,change your code files, create new ones, copy move, rename, delete... and Plastic will detect all the actions you did and displays them together so you can quickly check them in and get back to coding.

Tracking all these changes helps later to have a smooth merging experience, so you can enjoy the benefits of branching with no restrictions.

So in summary, you can continue using Plastic SCM and GitHub (although there is not a specific plugin for the INTEL-XDK).